# Telegram Bot PHP won't work (Running Apache on Xampp)

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, command

I am building a bot for Telegram that basically the user will be able to run a command and it will return some text. I am running Apache servers on Xampp. I already tested capturing some Arrays from user and I can capture it.

Not sure if maybe I have to run it on SSL Web Servers? or is there a function that I can use instead with Apache?

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$botToken = "";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {
    case "/test":
        sendMessage($chatId, "test");
        break;
    case "/hi":
        sendMessage($chatId, "hey there!");
        break;
    default:
        sendMessage($chatId, "default");
}

function sendMessage ($chatId, $message) {
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage? chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);
}

  ?>
```

These are the errors I get:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant website - assumed 'website' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php on line 29
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=default): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php on line 30

Comment: The one looks like you are missing quotes for the key name: `$GLOBALS[website]` => `$GLOBALS['website']` or probably `$` => `$GLOBALS[$website]` *(aka syntax error / typo)*?

Comment: When I do that it only appears the second error and when I run the command in the bot it doesn't do anything. Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=default): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php on line 30

Comment: Does that mean I have to get SSL?

Comment: No, you are receiving a valid json return at that link, so it is working. Have you followed the documentation on their site regarding how to connect to their API and make proper calls?

Comment: Yes I have. I have already setup commands. They show up as options in my bot but when I run them they don't do anything. Do I have to setup httpd-ssl.conf? Maybe I need to enable SSL on Apache? Not sure man please help!

Comment: I changed URL to CURL like this $curl = $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".curlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($curl);                 >>> its giving me this error now: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curlencode() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php(23): sendMessage(NULL, 'default') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socializers_bot\index.php on line 29. << ONLY ERROR IT GIVES ME NOW